# Where I can download ram gita of Skandpuran

Tags: rama, skanda-purana, ramayana

Is there any link where I can download or buy "ram gita of Skandpuran"?
Is it available offline?

Comment: https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/minigita/sriram?language=dv&field_nsutra_value=1, also present on archive

Comment: That's ram gita of adhyatm ramayan

Comment: maybe here https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism

Comment: https://archive.org/details/20230211_20230211_1856 Ram Gita from Skanda Purana Nirvana khanda. @Rambhakt Niroj Prasad

Comment: Thanx a lot dear